# Future of WPF and free controls ?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft, wpf, ui

I am willing to work on a personal project that I would like to release publicly. I am working with Silverlight and have experience with XAML, as it is my full-time job.

It is enjoyably for me to create UIs in Blend and XAML. I am also a big fan of C# language. I don't know what I would do without LINQ now.

Anyways, I was looking at using WPF for my personal project. It seems that a lot of the controls out on the web are pay for items. The only place I have found to have a significant number of free controls is the WPF extended framework on codeplex.

I want to make a financial application and need a powerful datagrid type of control that will allow me to enter transaction data. I haven't found such control for free in the net. It doesn't seem like there is much free community libraries/controls out there for Microsoft products.

So, I was wondering if WPF would be the right way for me to go. I couldn't find any information on WPF usage in Windows 8, which coming very soon. I don't know Microsoft's plans for this technology.

Would it be a better idea to use something different for the UI instead of WPF?

Answer (score 4):

A good post on future of WPF in Windows 8 - [WPF In Windows 8 Metro](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c79ec684-aac1-451d-9921-be8c8863b3b2)

- [discussion about Windows 8 - What is the future of WPF applications?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/54a99549-c634-4d45-87d6-15fd3bab483b)

Unfortunately most good quality WPF controls *are commercial* - [good WPF control libraries out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/915586/1437962). However, there are some limited number of **Free controls** that you might look:

- [MSDN - control Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752324.aspx)
- [FREE WPF controls](http://learndotnetprogramming.com/free-dot-net-controls-libraries/)
- [WPF C# Ribbon Control Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23199/WPF-C-Ribbon-Control-Library)
- [Wpf Control Library Software](http://wpf-control-library.winsite.com/)
- [Download free WPF ribbon control (Windows Scenic and Office 2007 style, too)](http://uxpassion.com/blog/old-blog/download-free-wpf-ribbon-windows-scenic-office-2007-style)